# is the adsorption of resveratrol within wine or grapes linked with the time it was kept in your mouth?

Tags: biochemistry, absorption

This question is about resveratrol in wine or grapes and not in some special delivery system.

If one is drinking some wine or eating grapes, does it matter if they keep it in their mouth a bit so the resveratrol within the wine or grapes get absorbed better?

I know now all nutrients can be gotten into onces body via buccal method so I am asking the experts what is the case with resveratrol from wine or grapes.

Comment: This is a good question!  I suspect that buccal delivery depends on the molecule in question being membrane permeable, or else on the creation of microlesions that give direct access to the bloodstream.  Wine doesn't create microlesions so membrane permeability is probably the issue.  You could look up the octanol-water partition coefficient of resveratrol to get an idea of its membrane permeability.

Answer (score 1):

This article on the [bioavailability or resveratrol](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1749-6632.2010.05842.x) seems to partly support your assumption: Keeping it in the mouth for a bit longer rather than swallowing directly might help to facilitate the uptake.

However, the solubility of resveratrol in water is apparently as low as 30 mg/L.